# Cart and mini cart are not cleared after check out and Success page

Tags: shopping-cart, magento1.9.3

Both my shopping cart and mini cart are not emptied after checkout and Success page.

Quota lifetime is already set to zero.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141400/cart-not-empty-after-order-place-success-magento-1-9-3 look at this post

Comment: The successAction code suggested returns a HTTP ERROR 500.

Answer (score 0):

Added the following to the success.phml:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

$quote->delete();
```